# How to resolve a required class was missing while executing : java/sql/SQLException

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have old project and whenever I run the command like `mvn clean install` or `mvn datanucleus:enchance` I am getting errors like

> Failed to execute goal
> org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.1.1:enhance (default) on
> project springboot-appengine-standard: Execution default of goal
> org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.1.1:enhance failed: A
> required class was missing while executing
> org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.1.1:enhance:
> java/sql/SQLException

I have the following pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.google.appengine.demos</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-appengine-standard</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>springboot-appengine-standard</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
 
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version> <!-- DO NOT UPDATE w/o MANUAL TESTING -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>


    <datanucleus.version>3.1.3</datanucleus.version>
    <datanucleus.plugin.version>3.1.1</datanucleus.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Securtiy Start.. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>

    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20230227</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.42.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev188-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-admin-directory</artifactId>
        <version>directory_v1-rev110-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.30.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev581-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.75</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.75</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>merchantsdk</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.122</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>permissionssdk</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.109</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- [START cloudplugin] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- [END cloudplugin] -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> 
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <api>JDO</api>
                <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                <fork>false</fork>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have the following datanucleus.properties file:

```
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:derby:eg;create=true 
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=root
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=root

datanucleus.autoCreateTables=true
datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=true
datanucleus.autoCreateColumns=true
datanucleus.autoCreateConstraints=true
datanucleus.RetainValues=true
```

I have tried updating the maven-datanucleus-plugin to different version. But, it didn't work. **How can I solve the above issue?**

Comment: Yes, upgrading the org.datanucleus plugin works for me. I did update the version to:     <version>3.2.0-m1</version>.